# Using google app engine in development environment to query objects?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The default app_engine development interactive console at http://localhost/_ah/admin is

```
from google.appengine.api import users

# Say hello to the current user
user = users.get_current_user()
if user:
  nickname = user.nickname()
else:
  nickname = "guest"
print "Hello, " + nickname
```

I have model which is like

```
class Page(db.Model):
    page_views = db.IntegerProperty()
    language = db.StringProperty()
```

I can list entites and see values there, but how can I run queries in interactive console? 
I tried

```
from models import Page

pages = Page.all()
```

But it fails, I am sure this is wrong, but what is right way of querying?

Thank you

Comment: What error does it fail with?

Comment: Is `models.py` at the top level of the application? Are you able to print `sys.path` in the console?

Comment: it works, models was not in top level of application which caused this. Thank you Wooble for your help

Comment: You need to post your solution as an answer. Also, what on earth does the first part of your question have to do with the rest?

Comment: Nick, the first part as I said is the default interactive console text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was not in top-level directory

```
from top.models import Page
```

this worked for me